# DragQueryFile always returns 0

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying the access files in the clipboard using VBA in PowerPoint, but DragQueryFile always returns 0.

Here my code snipped

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal uFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal uFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" ( ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" ( ByVal HDROP As Long, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Const CF_HDROP As Long = 15

Private Sub test_clipboard()
Dim nHandle As Long
If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_HDROP) > 0 Then
    If OpenClipboard(0) <> 0 Then
        nHandle = GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP)
        If nHandle <> 0 Then        
            ' Query number of files in clipboard -> returns always 0
            Debug.Print CStr(DragQueryFile(nHandle, GetNumOfFiles, vbNullString, 0)) 
        End If
        CloseClipboard
    End If
End If

End sub
```

I'm on Windows 10 and Office 2013.

There is a similar post for C# ([DragQueryFile returns 0 when I try to get file count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657996/dragqueryfile-returns-0-when-i-try-to-get-file-count)), but I'm calling OpenClipboard an CloseClipboard already.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this working [vba-read-file-from-clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913373/vba-read-file-from-clipboard#answer-2913670)?

Comment: Found the issue. It is the declaration at top. Just figured out that I have to replace long by longptr. Now it's working.

Comment: So you use `Office x64`! That's a fact you should have revealed at the beginning:( Are you aware of the [pros and cons](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261#32or64Bit=2013)?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with tmp_hallenser's comment, but thought it would would be better to lay it out more clearly.

One should change this two function definitions:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal uFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DragQueryFile Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "DragQueryFileA" ( ByVal HDROP As LongPtr, ByVal UINT As Long, ByVal lpStr As String, ByVal ch As Long) As Long
```

That is necessary because HDROP is a memory address and as such is going to be a different size according to the system.

The type LongPtr [will always be the appropriate size](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/longptr-data-type).